# Wait for a <FocusOut> action to be completed before app termination

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In a part of my application i have a tkinter textbox that whenever the `<FocusOut>` event is triggered by it the content of textbox is stored in database. This work fine only if user does not directly closes the application main window (right after inserting some text in textbox). What i would like to achieve is to find a solution that program wait till textbox content is stored in database and then it gets close. One solution is to use `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", store_textbox_content_in_db)` but it just write to DB every time that app is closed even when there has been no change in textbox widget ( assuming a change has happened whenever textbox is focused out). Here is a MWE:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3


def action():
    """when <FocusOut> event is triggered by textbox"""
    txt_content = textbox.get("1.0", tk.END)
    query = f"""
                UPDATE Test Set text = "{txt_content}" WHERE rowid =1;
            """

    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    cursor.close()


# table creation
sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('DB.db')
query = """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (
                text   TEXT
            );
        """

cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)

# inserting an empty row
query = """
        INSERT INTO Test (text) Values("");
        """
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)

sqliteConnection.commit()
cursor.close()

# GUI creation
root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(root)
textbox.pack(side="top")

textbox.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda e: action())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just check whether the text box has the focus inside the callback of `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` and if yes, save the content.

Comment: But is there an alternative way  instead of using `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` ?

Comment: Saving on blur (i.e. focus out) seems like sketchy UX to me - this behavior is a side effect. IMHO you're better off including a "Save" button or something similar. This solves two problems: 1) It prevents the user from quitting with unsaved content because you can check whether or not the `textbox` content has changed since they last clicked "Save", and 2) It avoids the issue of the user *unintentionally* saving something they didn't want to just because they accidentally clicked away from the text field. Putting the user in a position to accidentally do something is best avoided.

Comment: Remember: Minimal UI design isn't about having as little as possible, it's about having as little as *necessary*

Comment: why do you want to run it without submit button? what will the user do if the text typed needs to be edited?

Comment: @SuramuthuR well, the textbox is always there, so user can edit it whenever he likes, that is not an issue.

Comment: @JRiggles Thanks for the tips, I will definitely take them into consideration.